# integer input in switch case and user enter strings

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am writing code for my switch case. I am taking input from the user and printing the respective day based on the input. But my question is, if user is giving string input it is printing case 0 statement as output. Can anyone please correct this program?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int  days;
    scanf("%d",&days);

    switch(days){
        case 0: printf("Mon");break;
        case 1: printf("Tue");break;
        case 2: printf("Wed");break;
        case 3: printf("Thu");break;
        case 4: printf("Fri");break;
        case 5: printf("Sat");break;
        case 6: printf("Sun");break;
        default: printf("Plz enter a valid day(0-6) :( ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My output printing is :

```
>>a.out
  Naveen
  mon
```

Comment: `int  days;` --> `int  days = -1;`

Comment: For example what @BLUEPIXY said, but I'd recommend to use the **return value** of `scanf()` which tells you how many conversions were successfully performed. You expect `1`, but if the input can't be parsed as a number, you will get `0` (and if there was `EOF` or an error, you will get `EOF`). Always check the return value of functions that can return error indications!

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` won't modify your `int` if the format specifier isn't found in the input.

In this case, you're `switch`ing on an uninitialized `int`. Doing *anything* with uninitialized POD types is generally [A Bad Thing™](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), so you should take care that your value is initialized properly.

In this case, since you want it to trigger the `default` branch, initializing as `int days = -1;` (or as anything not in `[0,6]`) should do the trick.

PS: Note that `scanf` also returns an `int` telling you how many arguments it successfully found. This means you can check if `scanf` returned either `0` or `EOF` and handle this case separately - for example a more descriptive error message.

Answer (score 0):

loop until `days` was properly scanned

```
 while(scanf("%d",&days) != 1) getc(stdin);
```